# Faster alternative to Microsoft Access for simple ad-hoc queries

Tags: database, sql

Sometimes I use MS Access 2017 to perform database tasks: Union, Filter, Join ...
From time to time I receive data which I need to process, these are different, short, ad-hoc tasks, I need a tool where I can quickly import data and perform my queries.

I feel I've reached it's limits, my queries based on limited size data take minutes to run. (the same data is processed in no time in Spotfire, however that's not a database tool).

I'm looking for a faster tool now, which could do it more efficiently.

- I'm familiar with SQL, use Oracle's SQL developer and MS SQL Server Management studio, however they need a connection, can't connect to local databases
- I've a bit of understanding of R, a package there might be good too
- looking the internet SQLite seemed promising, however it's good for application development, I didn't see the way how could I do easily something simple in it.
- I've also found LibreOffice / OpenOffice suggested as similar tools, but I'm not sure those would have better performance.

---

(my data:

- 4-8 tables
- 1-10 MB each as txt files
- 10-300 k rows each

my Pc:

- HP EliteBook 840 G3, Intel i5-6300, 16 GB RAM
- Windows 7 Professional 64 bit, Office Professional Plus 2013 32 bit

what I've tried (without big improvement):

- embedding all data, adding indexes)

Comment: So a plain, file-based SQL database would fit your needs? Like [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/)?

Comment: Yes, seems like a solution!! (I check it before give a definite answer, but it is really something I need).

Comment: Hasn't all the functionality of MSAccess, so I was unsure if that's what you're after. Let me know if it fits, so I make it a full answer. I use it myself, btw ;)

Comment: It just knows what I need, please add it as an answer. Based on it, I've also tried [DB Browser for SQLite](https://portableapps.com/apps/development/sqlite_database_browser_portable) which is available through portableapps platform, it can create a table by csv import which I couldn't do in your tool. Otherwise SQLite studio seems to be more user friendly / interactive

Comment: The Firefox addon Sqlite Manager is better. Besides it's not something to do with your database development application. Are you sure you did database normalization? If it didn't work I recommend you to use an archive manager to compress files, if searching or filtering text is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you just confirmed, **[SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/)** is what you're looking for:

- it works with local database files, which are "portable" (you can just copy them to another machine, and even use them with other software)
- it can deal with the data sizes you've mentioned just easily (I use it with databases several Megabytes in size – other projects use SQLite databases even with several *hundreds* of Megabytes)
- you already found SQLite "promising", but obviously only lacked the GUI *SQLiteStudio* provides
- *SQLiteStudio is available cross-platform, so it works with your setup
- it's leight-weight and (compared with LibreOffice which you named) has much faster startup and a much smaller "footprint"
- it comes with an integrated database browser as well as with a query editor

[image: SQLiteStudio] [image: SQLiteStudio]
<sup>Screenshots: database browser, query editor (source: [SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I'm using *SQLiteStudio* myself, and am quite happy with it.